# Cassandra collection is not inserting Map value

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have this cassandra table

```
create table navigation_items
(
    navigation_key text,
    key_name_1 text,
    key_name_2 text,
    values map<text, frozen<navigation_item_value>>,
    PRIMARY KEY(navigation_key, key_name_1)
);

CREATE TYPE ks_mobApp.navigation_item_value (
    values map<text, text>
);
```

Here inserting data

```
INSERT INTO navigation_items(navigation_key, key_name_1,key_name_2,values)  VALUES('Tags', 'Sell', 'Electronics', {'k1':{values:{'k11':'v1','sas':'asasas'}}})
```

Data:

```
navigation_key | key_name_1 | key_name_2  | values
----------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------
           Tags |       Sell | Electronics | {'k1': {values: {'k11', 'v1'}}}
```

As you can see `'sas':'asasas'`is missing. I am using cassandra 2.1.9

Comment: Can you try with more recent version (2.1.15) ? It seems it's a bug with JSON support. May issue has been fixed in last 2.1 versions and 2.2.

Comment: yah correct, upgrading to 2.1.15 solved it